# mscorlib in .net core is missing in v3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, enums, netcoreapp3.1

I am working on wpf app. Using **ObjectDataProvider** am trying to bind enum to **combobox**. But mscorlib is not appearing when trying to reference in XAML. Does any package need to be installed for this?

Comment: `mscorlib` is specific to the old .NET Framework.

Comment: Is there an alternate for this in .net core? or should i refer some other assembly to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to reference `mscorlib`, just map the namespace to `System.Runtime`:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="name"
    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime" 
    MethodName="GetValues"
    ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:YourType"></x:Type>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: code snippet Works!. I cant find any documentation related to it. Can you redirect so i get better insight?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2441

Answer (score 0):

On digging more on how to bind enums in .net core, found an another way of achieving the same as described below.

The default namespace in XAML window is

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

I observered that, even without referring the 'system.runtime' assembly in XAML. we can still parse an enum and bind in XAML. Here is the code that is tried and successfully works.

Enum

```
public enum Members
{
    Member1,
    Member2
}
```

XAML

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="local:Members"
                            x:Key="key"
                            MethodName="GetValues">
     <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
           <x:Type TypeName="local:Members"/>
     </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```